# regex to find string between repeating markers

Tags: python, regex, multiple-occurrence

I have a string that looks like this:

```
**** SOURCE#24 ****

[1]  Source Location [Local/Remote]          : Remote

 Remote Host Name : PNQ
 User Name        : foo

[2]  Source directory                        : HDPGWRF
[3]  Directory poll interval                 : 30
[4]  File name format                        : ACR_FILEFORMAT
[5]  Delete files from source                : y

**** SOURCE#25 ****

[1]  Source Location [Local/Remote]          : Remote

 Remote Host Name : PNR
 User Name        : foo

[2]  Source directory                        : HDPGWRF
[3]  Directory poll interval                 : 30
[4]  File name format                        : ACR_FILEFORMAT
[5]  Delete files from source                : y

**** SOURCE#26 ****
etc.....
```

I want a capture group that captures everything after the '[1]' up to the ends of the line that starts with [5], based on the Remote Host Name (eg PNR or PNQ). So only lines [1] through [5] around the selected name.

I've been trying lookahead and lookbehind and just can't figure this out. It looks like lookbehind is greedy, so if I search for the PNR section, it won't stop at the first [1] but grabs everything up to the first [1] in the PNQ section.

This is the closest I've got to making it work, but it only works if I search for the PNQ section:

```
re.search('SOURCE#.*?\[1\](.*?PNQ.*?.*?HDPGWRF.*?)\*', buf, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

This after combing through stackoverflow all afternoon :(

Comment: Thanks that worked in regex101, but didn't find the group on my python3.10.1 setup. It did give me something to go on though.

Comment: You have to use `re.MULTILINE`, I have added a Python demo in the answer.

Comment: Or a bit more precise match without multiline `\bSOURCE#.*\s*\n\[1](.*\s*Remote Host Name\s*:\s*PNR\b\s*User Name\s*:\s*\S+\n(?:\n\[\d+].*)+)` https://regex101.com/r/lu7Ouj/1

Answer (score 1):

You might use a pattern without the `re.DOTALL` flag but with the `re.MULTILINE` flag:

```
\bSOURCE#.*\s*^\[1](.*\s*^(?!\[\d+]).*\bPN[QR](?:\n(?!\[\d+]).*)*(?:\n\[\d+].*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bSOURCE#` Match literally starting with a word boundary
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `\s*^` Match optional whitspace chars until a start of the line
- `\[1]` That matches `[1]`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*` match the rest of the line
  - `\s*^` Match optional whitspace chars until a start of the line
  - `(?!\[\d+])` Negative lookahead, assert that the lines does not start with `[digits]`
  - `.*\bPN[QR]` Match `PNB` or `PNQ` at the end of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!\[\d+]).*)*` Match all following lines that do not start with `[digits]`
  - `(?:\n\[\d+].*)*` Match all following lines that do start with `[digits]`
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ubyTuK/1) and [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/hjzpB4/1) that will not over match using only PNR and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UrvTa2)

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to make a Python object of the numbered-filtered items, you can try :

```
import re

targets = ["PNR", "PNQ"]

with open("file.txt") as f:
    pat = r"\*+\ (SOURCE#\d+) \*+\s+(.+?Remote Host Name : (\w+).+?)(?=\*)"
    
    data = {
        m.group(1) : dict(re.findall(r"\[\d+\]\s*(.+?)\s*:\s*(.+)", m.group(2)))
        for m in re.finditer(pat, f.read(), flags=re.M|re.S)
        if m.group(3) in targets # or ["PNR", "PNQ"]
    }
```

Output :

```
import json; print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

{
    "SOURCE#24": {
        "Source Location [Local/Remote]": "Remote",
        "Source directory": "HDPGWRF",
        "Directory poll interval": "30",
        "File name format": "ACR_FILEFORMAT",
        "Delete files from source": "y"
    },
    "SOURCE#25": {
        "Source Location [Local/Remote]": "Remote",
        "Source directory": "HDPGWRF",
        "Directory poll interval": "30",
        "File name format": "ACR_FILEFORMAT",
        "Delete files from source": "y"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want a capture group that captures everything after the '[1]' up to the ends of the line that starts with [5], based on the Remote Host Name (eg PNR or PNQ). ..."*

Try the following *match pattern*.

```
(?ms)^\[1\].+?Remote Host Name\s*:\s*(?:PNR|PNQ).+?^\[5\].+?$
```

- `(?ms)`, toggle on *"multi-line"*, and  *"single-line"*, mode
- `^\[1\]`, match a line that begins with the text, *"[1]"*
- `.+?Remote Host Name\s*:\s*(?:PNR|PNQ)`, match all characters up to the literal text *"Remote Host Name"*, optional white-space characters, a *":"*, followed by *"PNR"*, or *"PNQ"*.
- `.+?^\[5\]`, match all characters, up to the first line that begins with, *"[5]"*
- `.+?$`, match all characters up to the first, end-of-line

Here is an example, where *s* is the text.

```py
import re
p = r'(?ms)^\[1\].+?Remote Host Name\s*:\s*(?:PNR|PNQ).+?^\[5\].+?$'
[print(m.group(), end='\n\n') for m in re.finditer(p, s)]
```

Output

```
[1]  Source Location [Local/Remote]          : Remote

 Remote Host Name : PNQ
 User Name        : foo

[2]  Source directory                        : HDPGWRF
[3]  Directory poll interval                 : 30
[4]  File name format                        : ACR_FILEFORMAT
[5]  Delete files from source                : y
```

```
[1]  Source Location [Local/Remote]          : Remote

 Remote Host Name : PNR
 User Name        : foo

[2]  Source directory                        : HDPGWRF
[3]  Directory poll interval                 : 30
[4]  File name format                        : ACR_FILEFORMAT
[5]  Delete files from source
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. While none of the suggestions worked "out of the box" (I tried them all), using clues from each I managed to cobble up something that worked by taking advantage of the fact that each block ended with a ': \d+'. Also I had forgot to mention that the blocks could be any size, from [1] to [x]. The regex i ended up using is:

```
re.search(r'\*\s*SOURCE.*?\[1\].*(?:PNR)(.*?HDPGWRF.*?:\ \d+)\n\n', buf, re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

The (?:PNR) was the missing part that kept me busy and couldn't figure out.

Comment: You can write `(?:PNR)` just as `PNR` Note that the pattern does not work for your example data, see https://regex101.com/r/etCbpA/1 Also when you use `re.DOTALL` and you have multiple repeated occurrences, your pattern will still only match the last one, see https://regex101.com/r/WmAvDb/1 In that case you can make the `.*` non greedy like `.*?` The pattern is also not matching all the `[digit]` lines after the as it stops after matching `: \d+` Can you share a regex101 link with the data that you are using?

Comment: You are correct. I didn't do much checking and just assumed my re.search worked based on the one test I did. I ended up using the following: 
    re.findall('SOURCE#\d+\s*\*{4}.*?\[1\](.*?)[\*\=]{4}', buf, flags=re.DOTALL) since the entire section ends with '===='. Then I look for my string in the list. Thanks.